# JS game - shooting in random directions

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working on a HTML5 canvas / Javascript based game. It is a fighter jet game, after I pass specific score my main boss will spawn. Everything works like I wanted to but, I dont how to do boss shooting. My jet fires a single bullet verticaly but my idea was to make the boss fire in random directions. At least 3 bullets at the same time, in diferent directions. I am not using jQuery at all just normal JS. Boss moves horizontaly from border to another border, but its not shooting, so I might need a little bit of help. Any ideas ?

[image]

Red lines are my idea of shooting. I am capable of checking bullet / jet collision.

Some code of boss (vertical) shooting.

```
function BossBullet() {
    this.srcX = 1304;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.drawX = 500;
    this.drawY = 0;
    this.width = 4;
    this.height = 16;
}

BossBullet.prototype.akt = function(X,Y) {

    this.noseX=X;
    this.noseY=Y;
};

BossBullet.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctxBullet.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
    this.drawY += 10;

    ctxBullet.drawImage(imgSprite, this.srcX, this.srcY, this.width, this.height, this.drawX, this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
   //strela[hudba].play();
    if (this.drawY > 700) {
        this.drawY= this.noseY;
        this.drawX= this.noseX;

    }
};
```

and this is how it looks like. It fires single bullet from bosses nose and goes down until it reaches its Y value 0 and respawns.

[image]

I tried to add to `this.drawY += 10;` also `this.drawX += 1;` but this way it doesnt move at all.
Any ideas how to change the directory of the bullet??

Comment: do you need a random angle? how do you define "direction" in your game?

Comment: can you show some code showing what you have tried?

Comment: The view is from top so i hope that helps. I will upload a printscreen from the game so it would be more understandable.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It reminds me of a similar game I made in java, mouse controlled vertical space shooter with customizable spaceships and store inbetween missions. :D

Comment: Screen added. so far everything that I tried to do was only a waste of time since the game did not even start...

Comment: Please show the code that works firing vertically and what you have tried to do to make it random angle.  once you have that you should then work on multiple bullets if you don't already have that... one thing at a time

Comment: I added code for shooting vertically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/nueT7/) (Use mouse clicks to fire bullets)

zch's answer is fine but the problem is that the HTML5 **canvas** coordinates system and the trigonometric cycle is different than usual and we need to do some math tricks to calculate the angle that matches the velocity update and the drawing of the bullets.

[image: comparison between coordinates systems]

Here follow the code that I used for the bullets:

```
// Bullet class
function Bullet(x, y, speed, angle,  width, height, colors){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.colors = colors;       
    this.frameCounter = 0;
}

Bullet.prototype.update = function(){        
    // (!) here we calculate the vector (vx, vy) that represents the velocity
    var vx = this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle-(Math.PI/2));
    var vy = this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle-(Math.PI/2));

    // move the bullet 
    this.x += vx;
    this.y += vy;       
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function(context, xScroll,  yScroll){       
    context.save(); 

    if(this.angle != 0) {
        // translate to the orign of system
        context.translate(this.x-xScroll, this.y-yScroll);  
        // rotate
        context.rotate(this.angle); 
        // translate back to actual position
        context.translate(xScroll-this.x, yScroll-this.y); 
    }
    // animate the bullets (changing colors)
    context.fillStyle = this.colors[this.frameCounter % this.colors.length];    
    this.frameCounter++;

    // draw the bullet
    context.fillRect((this.x-this.width/2) - xScroll, (this.y-this.height/2) - yScroll, this.width, this.height);

    context.restore();          
}
```

The `update` and the `draw` methods should be called every frame for each bullet.

Now compare this code presents inside the update function

```
var vx = this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle-(Math.PI/2));
var vy = this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle-(Math.PI/2));
```

with the code below, as answered by zch.

```
var vx = speed * Math.cos(angle);
var vy = speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

It's just a math transformation to match our angle system with the canvas rotate method. This is accomplished by rotate the first system by 90 degrees.

[image: angle system]

Notice that you can also do this way:

```
var vx = this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
var vy = this.speed * -Math.cos(this.angle);
```

**Trigonometry** is your ally to make fun games!

Remember to create the fire function for your boss:

```
Boss.prototype.fire = function(){

    var nBullets = 3; // number of bullets to fire
    for(var x = 0; x < nBullets; ++x){  

        // angle between PI/2 and 3PI/2 (in radians)
        var angle =  (1 + 2 * Math.random()) * Math.PI / 2;

        // create a new bullet
        this.bullets.push(new Bullet(this.x, this.y, 10, angle, 2, 15, this.bulletsColors));
    }        
}
```

The above code assumes that your boss have an array of `bullets`.

[See the full code and play demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/nueT7/)

Comment: You sir deserve a medal!!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

You would need to represent bullets bullets. For each bullet you need to store its position (x, y) and velocity along each axis (vx, vy). During each unit of time increase position by velocity:

```
x += vx;
y += vy;
```

You probably want bullets shot at random angle, but constant speed. You can generate velocities using trigonometry:

```
var angle = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
var vx = speed * Math.cos(angle);
var vy = speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

You can limit angle to smaller range if you don't want to shot in all directions. For example for range 5/4π to 7/4π:

```
var angle = (5 + 2 * Math.random()) / 4 * Math.PI;
```

Comment: [Unit circle](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Unit_circle_angles_color.svg) for angle references

Comment: No! `Math.random` does not take any arguments; and probably you don't want to shoot at the whole 2π range but say 5/4π to 7/4π

Comment: @Bergi, stupid firefox didn't warn me :P fixed

Comment: I tried to change also the X value but it did not help.

Comment: @Toesmash You may find some trouble with this code using canvas because of the canvas coordinate system. You need to define your system coordinates to match the canvas coordinate system and make changes accordingly.It's more like a trigonometry problem. (I'll post an approach of how to do this as soon as possible.)